# Get path to file (e.g. picture) in android device (e.g. cell phone, tablet...) from vba access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to get path string to android device or its SD card as be able to copy or get some files(e.g. pictures) to process further...

As I didn't find not so menu samples about...

1. I tried go get the file with file dialog `f = Application.FileDialog...` but the directory has not been showed in the dialog.
2. I follow some samples to get `getExternalFilesDir(...` but I get `Sub or function not defined` error message.
   Simply I need to get file from let say this address:
   `Computer\HUAWEI M2-801L\Internal storage\DCIM\Camera\12.jpg`
3. I tried to use `Environ()` go get external directory but I didn't success to open folder.

As well I need to count items there or choose the latest record etc in that directory etc.

I tried to work with WIA COMMON DIALOG but I stuck over there as well

please anyone to help

Comment: Please, show the code you tried, show some screenshots with your error and your desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trouble referencing Windows Portable Device files in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217593/trouble-referencing-windows-portable-device-files-in-vba)